# Get the last displayed WebVTT cue

Tags: ios

Supposing I am displaying a video in my app using HTTP Live Streaming (HLS) and using WebVTT subtitles. This is how my code should looks like (I didn't tried it as I don't have the appropriate backend for that)

```
try! composition.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, videoAsset.duration), ofAsset: videoAsset, atTime: kCMTimeZero)  
        let subtitleTrack = composition.addMutableTrackWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeSubtitle, preferredTrackID: CMPersistentTrackID(kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid))  
        try! subtitleTrack.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, subtitleAsset.duration), ofTrack: subtitleAsset.tracks[0], atTime: kCMTimeZero)  
        let playerVC = AVPlayerViewController()  
        presentViewController(playerVC, animated: false, completion: nil)  
        playerVC.player = AVPlayer(playerItem: AVPlayerItem(asset: composition))  
        playerVC.player!.play()
```

Beside displaying the subtitles on the video, will it be possible for the app to get the last displayed subtitle String for the user or the last retried one from the server? Something like this

```
While(playing){
let lastSubtitle = playerVC.player.lastDisplayedSubtitle();
print(lastSubtitle); // print the last displayed subtitle on the console
}
```